# How to create Google Docs document with text, using Google Drive JavaScript SDK V3?

Tags: google-drive-api

Here is: Web Application. Google Drive JavaScript SDK.

I try to create new file in Google Drive with format, that can be opened with Google Docs UI.

Made oAuth2 successfully. After that running that code to create file:

```js
// Creates file itself
function create(folderId) {
  var fileMetadata = {
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
    'name': 'mrHanky'
  }
  var media = {
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
    body: 'Haidee hooowwww i am mr. Hanky!'
  }
  gapi.client.drive.files.create({
    name: 'test_mr_hanky.doc',
    parents: [folderId],
    resource: fileMetadata,
    media: media,
    params: {
      uploadType: 'media'
    },
    body: 'Haidee hooowwww mr. Hanky!',
    fields: 'id'
  }).then(function(result) {
    console.log('File create: ', result)
    save(result.result.id).then(function(result) {
      console.log('File update', result)
    })
  })
}

// Adds content. Perhaps not correct using of sdk, but somehow it half-works
function save(fileId) {
  return gapi.client
    .request({
      path: '/upload/drive/v3/files/' + fileId,
      method: 'PATCH',
      params: {
        uploadType: 'media'
      },
      body: 'mr Hanky after save!'
    })
}
```

So, file was created, with name '**test_mr_hanky.doc**' (from function 'create'), but it can't be opened, just suggests me to download it!

BTW localy i can open it with LibreOffice with text: **mr Hanky after save!** (from function 'save')

**So, question is: how to create real Google-Docs file on Google-Drive with a text**, that can be really opened by google docs UI?

Please help! Really, trying to get that for already 3rd day!

Here are links for docs:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientrequestargs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you almost got everything right.

You just missed to specify the mimetype in the `Files.create` section. `fileMetadata` only contains the details about the file, it doesnt necessarily set the files mimeType to `application/vnd.google-apps.document`.

```
gapi.client.drive.files.create({
name: 'test_mr_hanky.doc',
parents: [folderId],
resource: fileMetadata,
media: media,
..
```

**So add mimeType in this part:**

```
gapi.client.drive.files.create({
name: 'test_mr_hanky.doc',
mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document', //add the mimeType property
..
```

Do this and you're good to go. I tested this on [Files.create Try-it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create#try-it) and it works.

Comment: Wow, you were right!! I was so close to an answer :)) thanx!

Comment: This code works in creating a doc file, but no content is populated.  The text passed in the 'body' of the request is not inserted into the file.  Any idea how to get the content to populate?

Comment: Anybody was able to upload json content to Google Doc document (application/vnd.google-apps.document)?